# Solving integral with substitution gives wrong result

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

I want to solve the integral:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(1+|x|^3)^4} \ dx.$$

I thought I could solve that via the substitution $u=1+|x|^3$ since then one has the integral:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3u^4} \ du.$$

But that seems to be wrong (probably the substitution does not work here since it is not differentiable at 0), and that's why this integral is 0, but it should be $\frac29$. So how do I solve this correctly?

Comment: I think your substitution is (twice) differentiable at zero, no? In any case, the problem was that $u=1+x^3$ for $x>0$ and $u=1-x^3$ for $x<0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is even, so rewrite the integral as

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{(1+|x|^3)^4}dx = 2\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+x^3)^4}dx$$

Now try your substitution.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this before, but without changing the lower border to $1$ after the substitution. Then it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Since $x^2dx=1/3d(x^3)$ using $u=x^3$ we have

$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^2}{(1+x^3)^4}=\int_0^\infty1/3\dfrac 1{(1+u)^4}du=1/3\left.\left( -1/3 \dfrac1{(1+u)^3}\right)\right|=1/9.$$

Now in your integral the function is even, so the answer is just $2\cdot 1/9=2/9$